# "A Java Exception has Occurred" Apache POI Error

Tags: java, apache, crash

Im writing a program in java that takes an excel sheet from a local file and uploads the values given into the program for some calculations. When I compile inside eclipse everything works exactly as it is supposed to, but when I create a runnable jar file, I get a popup error "A Java Exception has Occurred". I went through the code, and if i remove the method to load the values from the spreadsheet the runnable jar works just fine. But if i put the code back in to load the values, it breaks. What is happening in this block of code that causes the whole program to break?

```
    private static void loadValues() throws IOException{

    //FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("src/PricingData.xls"));
    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("F:/Sales/Stitt/PricingData.xls"));


    HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
    HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

    Cell cell = sheet.getRow(1).getCell(1);
    MLPPSF = cell.getNumericCellValue();
    cell = sheet.getRow(2).getCell(1);
    COPPSF = cell.getNumericCellValue();

    cell = sheet.getRow(3).getCell(1);
    GPPSF = cell.getNumericCellValue();
    cell = sheet.getRow(4).getCell(1);
    UPFINISHED = cell.getNumericCellValue();
    cell = sheet.getRow(5).getCell(1);
    LOWFINISHED = cell.getNumericCellValue();
    cell = sheet.getRow(6).getCell(1);
    DPPSF = cell.getNumericCellValue();

    cell = sheet.getRow(8).getCell(1);
    onePanelWaterHeater = cell.getNumericCellValue();
    cell = sheet.getRow(9).getCell(1);
    twoPanelWaterHeater = cell.getNumericCellValue();
    cell = sheet.getRow(10).getCell(1);
    saferoomCost = cell.getNumericCellValue();
    cell = sheet.getRow(11).getCell(1);
    solarPVCost = cell.getNumericCellValue();
    cell = sheet.getRow(12).getCell(1);
    metlundCost = cell.getNumericCellValue();
    cell = sheet.getRow(13).getCell(1);
    ervCost = cell.getNumericCellValue();
    cell = sheet.getRow(14).getCell(1);
    gasFireplaceCost = cell.getNumericCellValue();
    cell = sheet.getRow(15).getCell(1);
    woodFireplaceCost = cell.getNumericCellValue();

    cell = sheet.getRow(18).getCell(1);
    allCabVanPercent = cell.getNumericCellValue();
    cell = sheet.getRow(19).getCell(1);
    allAppliancePercent = cell.getNumericCellValue();
    cell = sheet.getRow(20).getCell(1);
    allLightFixPercent = cell.getNumericCellValue();
    cell = sheet.getRow(21).getCell(1);
    allPlumbFixPercent = cell.getNumericCellValue();
    cell = sheet.getRow(22).getCell(1);
    allFloorCoveringPercent = cell.getNumericCellValue();

    cell = sheet.getRow(25).getCell(1);
    DepositPercent = cell.getNumericCellValue();
    cell = sheet.getRow(26).getCell(1);
    Draw1Percent = cell.getNumericCellValue();
    cell = sheet.getRow(27).getCell(1);
    Draw2Percent = cell.getNumericCellValue();
    cell = sheet.getRow(28).getCell(1);
    Draw3Percent = cell.getNumericCellValue();
    cell = sheet.getRow(29).getCell(1);
    Draw4Percent = cell.getNumericCellValue();
    cell = sheet.getRow(30).getCell(1);
    Draw5Percent = cell.getNumericCellValue();
    cell = sheet.getRow(31).getCell(1);
    Draw6Percent = cell.getNumericCellValue();
    cell = sheet.getRow(32).getCell(1);
    Draw7Percent = cell.getNumericCellValue();
    cell = sheet.getRow(33).getCell(1);
    Draw8Percent = cell.getNumericCellValue();
    cell = sheet.getRow(34).getCell(1);
    Draw9Percent = cell.getNumericCellValue();

}
```

And the main is:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    initialize();
    try {
        loadValues();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    showGUI();
}
```

EDIT:

Here is the error when I run it through command line.

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Conference Room\SESI>java -jar SESI.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/use
rmodel/Cell
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 6 more

C:\Documents and Settings\Conference Room\SESI>
```

Comment: I suggest you catch the Exception; if exception.printStackTrace() doesn't output it, write it to System.err.  Run the program from the command line, if you don't already, so that there is a console to receive errors.  Failing, that, put in System.err.println statements to trace how far your program is getting.  If you can force a stacktrace, it is the fastest and easiest way to start getting a handle on what's going wrong.

Comment: Ive done a little more research since i posted this and found that it seems to be a problem with the "fileinputstream" not working correctly inside the JAR file. But im still a little lost as to where to go from here.

Comment: Files not working within JARs mostly has to do with attempting to create files inside the directory tree represented inside the jar -- using the "F:\a\b\c" format that you have, it should work as long as you have an F drive on what I assume is a Windows system with those directories, and if you have write access to the directories.  For "where to go", my original suggestion stands -- you need more information about what the error is and EXACTLY where it is thrown from.  A stacktrace will give you both.  Go get one.

Comment: Are those actually single backslashes in the filepath?  I'm surprised you don't get an error or warning there from eclipse -- you need to put two backslashes in order to result in the one backslash you need in a Windows filepath.

Answer (score 0):

To figure out what's wrong, you need to actually see the exception.  Just double-clicking the jar file will launch it using "javaw.exe", which has no console and therefore only reports that there was an exception -- without the stack trace.

Instead, start a command prompt and "cd" to where your jar file is.  Then, supposing that the jar name is "MyJarFile.jar", run this:

```
java -jar MyJarFile.jar
```

When run with "java.exe", your printStackTrace() will actually have a console in which to print the stack trace, which will point you to the offending line of code and state the type of problem.

UPDATE (following the posted exception):

Ah, since you require a third party dependency, you need to switch to something like this, running your main class explicitly and specifying a classpath containing all required classes:

```
java -cp path\to\ApachePoiJarName.jar;path\to\MyAppJarFile.jar my.main.class.package.MyMainClass
```

...with "path\to", "ApachePoiJarName", "MyAppJarFile", "my.main.class.package" and "MyMainClass" replaced with the appropriate name.

If the POI jar requires in turn its own dependencies, add the paths to those files to the class path as well (a list of jar paths separated by semicolons, no spaces between them).

Comment: I added the console output to the original question.

Comment: Great!  Please see my update to the original answer for the next step.

Comment: Using the format in the update, i receive error:

    Error: Could not find or load main class C:\SESI\SESI.jar

But I can see in my C: drive that its there

Comment: Zac, please make sure you don't have any spaces around the semicolons in your classpath, otherwise your second jar path is misinterpreted as the class name to execute.

Comment: Taking the spaces out from around the semicolon worked! The program opens up and loads the values as expected from the excel workbook. Now what do  I need to do to make it runnable by double clicking the jar file, instead of running it from command line?

Answer (score 0):

In reply to "*Now what do I need to do to make it runnable by double clicking the jar file, instead of running it from command line?*" (Tried to reply in a comment but the size limit was too small.)

In Eclipse, once you have a "run configuration" with which the project is running correctly:

- Right click the project -> Export... -> (from Java) -> Runnable JAR file
- Next
- Select from the drop-down list the run configuration that launches your project.
- In Export destination, browse to where you want the runnable jar exported and choose a jar file name.
- Under "Library handling" select "Package required libraries into generated JAR"
- Finish

Your jar file should now run normally.  Note that it opens with "javaw" by default, which does not show a console.  If you need a console to see some output, or if it fails and you want to see the exception, open a console where the jar is and run "java -jar MyJarName.jar" (no more need to specify the main class and dependencies).